# get expo build url in Gitlab CI

Tags: react-native, expo, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI to automate my expo project builds, for that I am using following commands to build and submit iOS app on TestFlight.

> expo build:ios --non-interactive --skip-credentials-check
>
> eas submit -p ios --latest --profile stage --non-interactive

The first command will return a build url, that url must be used in second command to submit build to TestFlight.

The issue is I am not able to get the url from expo build command, I tried using variable, but if I am using variable the command is not waiting for finish the command, so before the build finish next line is executed.

using variable

> VER_BUILD_URL=$(expo build:ios --non-interactive
> --skip-credentials-check)

Solution can be following:

1. I can get the url returned from expo build and can pass that url to eas submit

OR

2. expo must have a command to get the url directly from that command

Answer (score 2):

We solved this by getting the build id from the output of the new `eas build` command and storing it in a variable. The variable can then be used in the next stage. Not sure if you can use the same solution with `expo build:ios`, as we just started building our first app with expo and directly used `eas`.

```
.template:
  image: node:16-alpine
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .yarn
  before_script:
    - yarn install --cache-folder .yarn
    - apk add --no-cache bash git

build:
  extends: .template
  stage: build
  script:
    - npx eas-cli build -p ios --non-interactive --profile production | tee $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.build-result-ios
    - echo "IOS_BUILD_ID=$(sed -n "s/^Build details.*\/builds\/\([a-f0-9-]*\)$/\1/p" $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.build-result-ios)" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  image: node:16-alpine
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npx eas-cli submit -p ios --non-interactive --profile production --id=$IOS_BUILD_ID
  dependencies:
    - build-ios
  needs:
    - job: build-ios
      artifacts: true
```

As a side note: With `eas build` you can also use the `--auto-submit` [parameter](https://docs.expo.dev/build/automating-submissions/).